# How to include digits in string but not a specific set of digits

Tags: r, regex

I have a pattern to detect all digits and the specific units of measurement (mu) and two hormones mentioned in this string (kinetin and zeatin)

```
pattern = [0-9]| mu|kinetin|zeatin
```

However, this pattern matches ALL digits in a string and so it highlights 2,4 of 2,4-d which I do not want. How do I highlight all digits except that specific set?

I've provided an example below of what sort of string I am dealing with for reference

Here is an example string that has what I am referring to:

> `high-frequency somatic embryogenesis was achieved from an embryogenic cell suspension culture of acanthopanax koreanum nakai. stem segments were cultured on murashige and skoog (ms) medium containing auxins and cytokinins. opaque and friable embryogenic callus formed on ms medium with 4.5 mu m 2,4-dichlorophenoxyacetic acid (2,4-d) and 2.0 mu m kinetin or zeatin, but was highest on medium containing 4.5 mu m 2,4-d alone.`

Any help is greatly appreciated!! I am very very new to this so!

Comment: We were all new to this at one time so worry not. I'd like to make two suggestions. Firstly, whenever you give an example (or more than one), show the desired result. Secondly, make the example as short as possible while still retaining all of its essential characteristics. Here you might remove part of the text even if what's left is not a scientifically valid wording. I suggest you edit, mainly to show the desired result for the example.

Comment: You probably want `pattern = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*\\s*(?:mu|kinetin|zeatin)"`

Comment: please explain the  pattern = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*\\s*(?:mu|kinetin|zeatin)

Comment: It works for what I needed (not including the 2,4) but it no longer catches zeatin or kinetin. Is there another solution for this? Thank you so much!

Comment: So you need to match number + `mu` or `kinetin` or `zeatin`? Like with `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*mu\b|kinetin|zeatin`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/77oi0A/1)?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I just played around with this and found that \\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*\\s*(?:mu)|zeatin|kinetin gets the answer that I would like! However, I will use the code that you suggested above because you clearly know more than me with regex. I am wondering....how does your code exclude 2,4 but pick up the other numbers?

Comment: Ok, I have a clear understanding of the problem now. Just note that including a single alternative into a non-capturing group makes no sense, `mu` = `(?:mu)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find any numbers with `mu` as a measurement unit, or `kinetin`, or `zeatin` words.

You can use the following pattern:

```r
pattern = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*\\s*mu|kinetin|zeatin"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/77oi0A/2). It matches

- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*mu`:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:[.,]\d+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a `.` or `,` and then one or more digits
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
  - `mu` - a `mu` substring
- `|` - or
- `kinetin|zeatin` - `kinetin` or `zeatin` substring.

**Note** that `mu`, `kinetin` and `zeatin` in the above regex match substrings, even `mu` in `mute`. If you want to avoid this, add word boundaries:

```r
pattern = "\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*\\s*mu\\b|\\b(?:kinetin|zeatin)\\b"
```